# Prove that $f$ is constant on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Let $D$ be a bounded domain, let $f$ be analytic and never zero in $D$ and continuous up to the boundary of $D$. Assume that $|f|$ is constant on the $\partial D$.Prove that $f$ is constant on $D$.**

Firstly, i know how to do the question. But my confusion is the theorem of max and min modulus theorem itself. In the theorem in my book, it clearly states that the function $f$ needs to be a non constant function. However, in the answer for this question, the professor freely invoked the max and min modulus theorem. However, since $f$ is a constant function, can we still freely use the theorem?

Comment: You have to assume that $f$ is not constant, use the theorem and get a contradiction. Then your assumption has to be wrong and you proved that $f$ has to be constant.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt  If i assume $f$ is not a constant, then i use the theorem and it actually lead me to the conclusion that $f$ is a constant, is this a proof by contradiction as well?

Comment: Since you got a contradiction ($f$ is not constant $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is constant) your assumption ($f$ is not constant) has to be wrong and you get $f$ is constant. Yes, therefore it is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt oh thanks! i got a little confused as my past questions on proof by contradiction relies on a contradiction in other parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several versions of the maximum modulus principle.

One version is about non-constant holomorphic functions:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ a domain, and $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ a non-constant holomorphic function. Then $\lvert f\rvert$ has no local maximum in $U$.

Another version concerns holomorphic functions on a bounded domain with a continuous extension to the boundary:

> Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ a bounded domain, and $f \colon \overline{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function that is holomorphic on $D$. Then $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum on the boundary: $$\max_{\overline{D}} \lvert f(z)\rvert = \max_{\partial D} \lvert f(z)\rvert.$$

This version doesn't require the function to be non-constant. A corollary of it is that if the maximum of $\lvert f\rvert$ is also attained at some point of $D$, then $f$ is constant. Another corollary is the minimum modulus principle: if $f$ has no zeros in $D$, then $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its minimum on the boundary too, and the corresponding conclusion that if the minimum is also attained in $D$, then $f$ is constant [it is essential for the minimum principle that we assume that $f$ has no zeros in $D$].

It is this latter version that is used in the exercise. The assumptions imply that $\lvert f\rvert$ is constant on $D$, hence $f$ is constant.

Of course it happens that a version of the maximum (or minimum) modulus principle is used without that version having been explicitly stated (and proved) in the course.